# Pandas.plot does not plot all of row of a Series object

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a small sample code as below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temperatures = [4.4,5.1,6.1,6.2,6.1,6.1,5.7,5.2,4.7,4.1,3.9,3.5]
dates = pd.date_range('2016/10/29 5:30pm', periods=12, freq='H')
temp_series = pd.Series(temperatures, dates)

temp_series.plot(kind="bar")
```

I want my plot to be like this:

[image: Expectation]

(I tested it on google colab and it worked)

However, on my computer it turned out to be like this:

[image: Plot on my computer]

I suspected there might be some issue with pandas and matplotlib recent versions. However, I am still new to pandas so I don't really know how to debug this. My python is 3.9.0, pandas is 1.2.0, and matplotlib is 3.3.2.

Comment: it works in my env, try converting dates to strings, looking at the x-legend seems to be a problem regarding the date interpretation

Comment: I can get this to plot as expected with `seaborn`: `sns.barplot(data=time_series.reset_index(), x='index', y=0)` and then `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`, but not with `plt.bar` or `df.plot.bar`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney For me with pandas 1.2.1 it seems to work without problems

Comment: @JohanC i'm using 1.2.0. Let me see if there's an update for Anaconda, and then I'll try again. Thanks for following up on this.

Comment: @JohanC Updated to pandas 1.2.1 and this works without issue. So some bug in 1.2.0 I guess. I think this may have to do with how pandas creates periodic dates. This doesn't seem to be a matplotlib issue.  _Pandas uses a different datetime representation in case of equally spaced time series (and does not tell users about it, it seems)._ per a comment in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17419

Answer (score 0):

So I tried downgrading my pandas version from 1.2.0 to 1.1.5 and now it works. However, this is only a temporary solution by now. I would be very grateful if someone can explains this issue and how to actually fix it in the new version.